# UpdateSourceTrigger ignored

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, .net-3.5

I am using a CheckBoxColumn in a DataGrid. In general the binding works fine, but the UpdateSourceTrigger (set to PropertyChanged) is ignored and the property updates on LostFocus. What is my mistake or how can I change this behavior to update the property immediately? As far as I read, setting UpdateSourceTrigger should work.

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enable"
                                    Binding="{Binding Enable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Message"
                                Binding="{Binding Text}"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        <!-- [...] -->
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

I have this problem in my Silverlight page using the Silverlight Toolkit. I tried this simplified example in a WPF-application with the same behavior. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a DataGridTemplateColumn instead with a CheckBox inside.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bool">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enable}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: How does the CellEditingTemplate look like?

Comment: There is no need to define a CellEditingTemplate. The Checkbox binds directly to bound property